# Sending a XMLHTTP post with foxpro and I am getting the result "Auth failure needs full credentials "

Tags: foxpro, xmlhttprequest

I am using this code and instead getting back in the `lcResultText` the reponse I expect
I am getting back the result:

```
Auth failure needs full credentials
```

this is my code:

```
LOCAL xhr xhr = CREATEOBJECT("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

xhr.Open("post", "https://api.ahds.com/ext/apitest.php",.f.,"qqq","qqqq")
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded') xhr.send("custid="+"wwwaaaaaaa"+"&username="+"daaaaaad"+"&password="+"aaaaaaaa"+"&data="+lcMyData)

PUBLIC lcResultText

DO WHILE .T.

  IF XHR.readyState =4 EXIT XHR.readyState
  ENDIF

  ?XHR.readyState

ENDDO ?XHR.readyState ?xhr.status

lcResultText = xhr.responseText

? lcResultText xhr = null

Function UrlEncode( tcValue, llNoPlus )

  LOCAL lcResult, lcChar, lnSize, lnX

  * Do it in VFP Code

  lcResult=""

  FOR lnX=1 to len(tcValue)

    lcChar = SUBSTR(tcValue,lnX,1)

    IF ATC(lcChar,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789") > 0

      lcResult=lcResult + lcChar

      LOOP
    ENDIF

    IF lcChar=" " AND !llNoPlus

      lcResult = lcResult + "+"

      LOOP
    ENDIF

  * Convert others to Hex equivalents

  lcResult = lcResult + "%" + RIGHT(transform(ASC(lcChar),"@0"),2)

ENDFOR 


RETURN lcResult
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic XHR here is correct, but you aren't supplying sufficient credentials for the `https://api.ahds.com/ext/apitest.php` service.  You will need to contact **ahds.com** to obtain the correct format their API expects authentication credentials to be provided as.

Most likely, they will want them to be added to HTTP headers, similar to your existing use of `xhr.setRequestHeader` to add a *Content_Type* header.